# Powershell: Listing billions of folders fastly

Tags: powershell

We have to check ALL ACLs (for an specific user) on a large UNC folder and some local folders with millions and millions of files.

`Get-ChildItem` is painfully slow, so I am trying using the `[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($Spath, '*.*', 'AllDirectories')` method as a first step to get ALL folders and subfolders and then use the results to look for the ACLs folder by folder.

This works blazing fast, but when I try to export the list to a CSV I always get the string lenght and not the contents.

Really simple example:

```
$Spath = "C:\Users\user1"

Try {
    $Folders = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($Spath, '*.*', 'AllDirectories')
} catch {
    $_.Exception.message
}
$Folders | Export-Csv C:\Temp\test.csv -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```

All I get is a list with numbers.

It is obvious for me that this is a newbie problem, but would you please help me?.

Regards.

Comment: You can try as workaround: $Folders >> C:\Temp\test.csv

Comment: This should help - "Export-Csv exports a table of object properties and their values. Since your script is producing string objects, and the only property they have is length, that's what you got.

If you just want to save the list, use Out-File or Set-Content instead of Export-Csv."https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450616/export-csv-exports-length-but-not-name

Comment: `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines('C:\Temp\test.csv', $Folders)` see [File.WriteAllLines Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Yep! @BrettLarson and JosefZ were right. All nice and done. Thanks!